# Finding first occurrence of character and then printing WORD (dont want the index)

Tags: python

I want to find the first occurrence of a specific letter and then print out the word where the character first appears. The letter can be upper or lower case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split() method:

```
def fun(string, char):
    for word in string.split():
        if char in word:
            return word
    return None


print(fun('abc def ghjk ldsa l', 'e'))
```

Above code will result in:

```
def
```

Comment: thank you! How would i ensure this is case sensitive?

Comment: By using exceptions: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp or by checking if input variables 'string' and 'char' are type of string with isinstance function: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-check-if-a-variable-is-string/

Comment: @Marcin-99--you can make it case insensitive by: 1) `char = char.lower()` (first line of function). And, 2) change conditional to `if char in word.lower()`